# javascript post not doing function but load url

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I am creating Stratego.
(the error is farther down)
so i am creating the map when the page is loadet whit:

```
turn = true;
komboType = "2kombo";
GameOpsetning = [];
GameOpsetningEnemy = [];
$(document).ready(function() {   
    createmap();
}
```

and then i do some console log to make sure it works..

```
function createmap () {
if (!GameStarted) {
    console.log("GameOpsetning" + GameOpsetning);
    if(GetSetup(Gameid)){
        console.log("GameOpsetning1" + GameOpsetning);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("GetSetup : error");
    }
```

and here the error comes, it will open the file "game.php" whit no error. but it will not do eny thing in side the post/funcion. It will not do the alert or the if or console.log?

```
    function GetSetup (Gameid) {
    console.log("GameOpsetning3: " + GameOpsetning);
    if ($.post("game.php", { gameid: Gameid }, function(data) {
        alert(data);
        var data2 = JSON.stringify(data);
        alert(data2);
        //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (data2.status2 && data2.status2 != "false") {
            console.log("data.game: " + JSON.stringify(data.game));
            GameOpsetning = JSON.stringify(data.game);
            GameOpsetningEnemy = JSON.stringify(data.enemygame);
            komboType = data.type;
            turn = data.turn;
            console.log("GameOpsetning5: " + GameOpsetning);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("error: ");
            return false;
        }
    })){
        console.log("post: done");
    }else{
        console.log("post: error");
    }
    console.log("GameOpsetning4: " + GameOpsetning);

}
```

the console output:

```
GameOpsetning
GameOpsetning3: 
post: done
GameOpsetning4: 
GetSetup : error
```

there is no console errors and the page is return JSON

and it have try ed to do like:

```
console.log("GameOpsetning" + GameOpsetning);
GetSetup(Gameid);
console.log("GameOpsetning1" + GameOpsetning);
if (CheckGame()) {
```

then the console log is:

```
GameOpsetning
GameOpsetning1
GameOpsetning3: 
post: done
GameOpsetning4: 
GetSetup : error
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing `if($.post("game.php",...` What is the result of this if test? Always `true`. Because anything that is not false, 0 or undefined is true. You're not testing the *result* of an ajax call, you're testing *an ajax call* (a function).

Same with `if(GetSetup(Gameid))`. GetSetup(Gameid) returns : `console.log("GameOpsetning4: " + GameOpsetning)`. `if(GetSetup(Gameid))` result is `undefined`, which explains the `GetSetup : error` output.

Type this in your console : `if(console.log('test')) alert("yay")` : it won't alert "yay", it will just log 'test' and return undefined. This is your `if(GetSetup(Gameid))`.

Same way, if you type `if($.post("game.php")) alert('yay')`, it will alert yay, because the test is always true, whatever the result of the `$.post`.

Comment: that make sense. I have allow try ed whit out the if. same result. from `if ($.post("game.php", { gameid: Gameid }, function(data) {` to `$.post("game.php", { gameid: Gameid }, function(data) {` then it have to do the if that have a return? http://jsfiddle.net/7nq9wmq6/

Comment: Yes, first make the ajax call, when the response comes back, test it. Place the `if` in the callback function.

Comment: i addet `.post("game.php", {.....).fail(ajaxError);  function ajaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('$.post error: ' + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    };` and find the error. it was a `,` to much. But now the console output http://jsfiddle.net/888mkcy7/